# how to return values in json that contain models to be associated using JBuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jbuilder

I would like to return values in json that contain models to be associated using JBuilder.
But I don’t know how to do it. And I encounter the error that “undefined method  xx”
Here is my setting of rails.

Model

**app/models/item.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
include UserImageUploader[:image]
has_many :item
```

**vim app/uploaders/user_image_uploader.rb**

```
# MiniMagick
require 'image_processing/mini_magick'

class UserImageUploader < Shrine
  include ImageProcessing::MiniMagick
  # The determine_mime_type plugin allows you to determine and store the actual MIME type of the file analyzed from file content.
  plugin :determine_mime_type
  plugin :store_dimensions
  plugin :pretty_location
  plugin :processing
  plugin :recache
  #The versions plugin enables your uploader to deal with versions,
  #by allowing you to return a Hash of files when processing.
  plugin :versions

  process(:store) do |io, context|
    original = io.download

    thumbnail = ImageProcessing::MiniMagick
      .source(original)
      .resize_to_limit!(600, nil)

    original.close!

    { original: io, thumbnail: thumbnail }
  end

  #plugin :versions

  #plugin :delete_promoted
  #plugin :delete_raw
end
```

**items_controller.rb**

```
@items = Item.includes(:user).page(params[:page] ||= 1).per(8).order('created_at DESC')
render 'index', formats: 'json', handlers: 'jbuilder'
```

**Item/index.json.jbuilder**

```
json.array! @items do |t|
  json.id t.id  //get the value normally
  json.created_at t.created_at //get the value normally 
  Json.user_id t.user.id  //undefined method `id’ 
  json.user_original_img t.user.image_url(:original) //undefined method `image_url' 
end
```

As above, I could not get the value of the model being associated.

By the way, I could check the value correctly with rails console.

**Bundle exec rails c**

```
Item.first.user.image_url(:original)

  Item Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  `items`.* FROM `items` ORDER BY `items`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
=> "https://xx.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/store/user/1/image/original-xx”

Item.first.user.id
   (19.0ms)  SET NAMES utf8mb4,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
  Item Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  `items`.* FROM `items` ORDER BY `items`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
=> 1
```

Let me know what points I am wrong with.

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: You've cut the error message into halve, what does the last bit say? *"NameError: undefined local variable or method \`id' for ........."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that some items in `@items` list, doesn't have associated user, or their `user_id` field is `nil`. Then `item.user` would be `nil`. When you do `nil.image_url` you get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'image_url' for nil:NilClass` .

You could add a foreign key constraint between `Item` and `User` in your migration, to avoid problems like this:

```
add_foreign_key :items, :users
```

NOTE:
Adding the foreign key would still allow empty values. You'd also have to add the following in your migration file to avoid empty values in `user_id` column:

```
change_column_null :items, :user_id, false
```

Thanks to @3limin4t0r for pointing this out.

Comment: Adding the foreign key would still allow empty values. You'd also have to add `change_column_null :items, :user_id, false` (if not already present).

Comment: @3limin4t0r  I got a hint from your answer and found casuse of the problem.

Comment: The cause of the error was that nil was in some columns of user_id.  thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

**app/models/user.rb**

```
include UserImageUploader[:image]
has_many :item
```

should be `has_many :items`, not terribly confident on this, but this may be the reason you're finding blank columns in your db. A `has_many, belongs_to` relationship should default to required.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'll make change it